# Track where users come from in PHP?

Tags: php, tracking

Is it possible to find out where the users come from? For example, I give a client a banner, and the link. The client may put the banner/link to any website, lets say to a site called www.domain.com.

When the user click the banner, is it possible to know where he coming from(www.domain.com)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at the [HTTP_REFERER](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-http-referer-variable/) variable. It will tell you what site the user was on before he came to your site.

Comment: Users can tell their browser not to send the referrer information.

Comment: Users can also tell the browser to not display images. Nothing you can do about that

Comment: So what should I do? Using HTTP_REFERER? Is there any other methods?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You give the client a unique URL, like `www.yourdomain.com/in/e10c89ee4fec1a0983179c8231e30a45`. Then, track these urls and accesses in a database.

The real problem is tracking unique visitors.

Comment: Unique users? By IP? Altho dynamic IP users will give me trouble. Well, I like your unique URL ideas. I will consider it. Thanks gnud :)

Comment: It's hard to know if another user is a new user, or the same one who followed the link again. Or a click-bot. That's what I mean by unique users.

Answer (score 1):

See

```
 $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

Although that can't always be trusted as it's set by the client but you may not care in your case.

Answer (score 1):

In some scenarios, $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] will only work when php (php.ini) is configured with register_globals bool configured to on.

Register globals can allow exploitation in loosely coded php applications. Commonly in apps that allow users to post data.

I have used the following method in the past to check referrers in applications where I controll the operator input.

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['url_referer']))
{
$_SESSION['url_referer'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
```

Without hashing strings in session variables, I do not know of a more efficient practice. Does anyone know the best practices?

Finest Regards,

Brad

Answer (score 0):

The only chance is that you use a unique ID (as pointed out by gnud). This ay you can track the incomming links. Referrer may be altered/removed from browsers or proxies (many companies do that).

Using the IP to track unique visitors is a bad idea. AOL still pools the IPs and you might use different IPs every few minutes and with proxys yiur counting will be not very accurate.

I'd say, go with the unique ID.