# Checking where the user came from (stumbleupon)

Tags: php, anonymous-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Track where users come from in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519349/track-where-users-come-from-in-php)

How can you check if a (unique) visiter/user was directed to your site from stumbleupon, google or facebook in php?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the referer header `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`